# Python xpath to extract the first part html from html which has more than three same div

Tags: python, html, xpath

The python xpath is used to extract the div html from the html. For example, as shown the following html.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="headline">
    <h2>123</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="headline">
    <h2>abc</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    <div class="headline">
    <h2>efg</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I just want to extract the following part div html for me or just extract the 123 text :

```
    <div class="headline">
    <h2>123</h2>
    </div>
```

my code is shown as following:

```
  title = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "headline")]/h2')
```

but I got all the three html data. Actually, I just want to get the 123 data html part. Please just use the xpath method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this part:

```
<div class="headline">
<h2>123</h2>
</div>
```

Use this Xpath:

```
(//div[contains(@class, "headline")])[1]
```

Your xpath returned a List of matching elements, the `()[1]` part returns the first Item on that List.